# React <Text> with ternary conditional operator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am pretty new to react-native and I don't know how to find a solution for what I am trying to achieve.
I have multiple functions which either return null or a string. I want to show the return value when it's not null. for example my functions are

```
//these functions either return null or a string
const a =() => { ...};
const b =() => { ...};
const c =() => { ...};
```

I have a `<Text>` component and I want to show the return values from the functions inside my `<Text>` component.

Right now I am doing it in the following way

```
<Text>
  {a()}{b()}{c()}
</Text>
```

Now everything works fine and The text will only show the return value when it is a string.

I want to add a ternary conditional operator and check whether a new variable `tmp` is undefined or not. if `tmp` is not undefined the `<Text>` should show `tmp` value otherwise It should show the return value of the function that I have above.

```
<Text>
  {tmp !== undefined ? tmp : }{a()}{b()}{c()}
</Text>
```

if I do something like

```
<Text>
  {tmp !== undefined ? tmp : (
  a();
  b();
  c();
  )}
</Text>
```

and if `tmp` is undefined it will show the null returned from function too. but I don't want the null returned from functions to be show like the first example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could your `a`, `b`, and `c` functions return an empty string instead of `null`?

If so, you could rewrite your answer as:

```js
<Text>{tmp || `${a() + b() + c()}`}</Text>
```

If not, it's a little more cumbersome to write, but the same idea would work:

```js
<Text>{tmp || `${a() || ''}${b() || ''}${c() || ''}`}</Text>
```

Comment: Dry it up like this `[a, b, c].reduce((s, f) => \`${s}${f()||""}\`, "")`

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works. 
Is there any way to make it more readable and optimize it even more?

Comment: `[a, b, c].map(f => f() || '').join('')` would work, though I don't like single-letter naming

Comment: `[a, b, c].map(f => f()).join('')` actually works even if the outputs are `null`, that's even slightly shorter (=

Comment: @abe thanks dude. It's much cleaner and readable.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to accomplish this, In React Native you can have nested `<Text>` components. Insted of using a ternary operator, I would do it like this:

```js
<View>
  {tmp && (
    <Text>
      {_a && <Text>{_a}</Text>}
      {_b && <Text>{_b}</Text>}
      {_c && <Text>{_c}</Text>}
    </Text>
  )}
</View>
```

See the snack https://snack.expo.dev/@abranhe/undefinedvalues

Comment: I was looking for an optimized way of doing it. I don't know if using multiple `<Text>` is better and optimized or using a ternary and using only one `<Text>`.

Comment: Sometimes when working with JSX readability is key, but again that would be my way of doing it.

Comment: In addition to that, React Native does not render when is a falsy value like (`null`, `undefined` or `''`) so you can even do something like `<Text>{a()} {b()} {c()}</Text>`, but again that's horrible code. Check https://snack.expo.dev/@abranhe/fallacknull